# AssetBundleBuild addressableNames vs assetNames

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can someone help me understand the difference between the AssetBundleBuild.addressableNames and AssetBundleBuild.assetNames?

Also can I use BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles with AssetBundleBuild[] parameter to build specific asset bundles and not all of them (the overload without this parameter) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AssetBundleBuild.assetNames` identifies the exact location and name for *bundling an asset*. (assume *buildMap* is of type `AssetBundleBuild`)

```
buildMap[0].assetNames[0] = "Assets/Textures/stinky_pupper_smol.jpg";
```

`AssetBundleBuild.addressableNames` is an optional nickname for *loading the asset* its array index corresponds to.

```
buildMap[0].addressableNames[0] = "DogTexture";
```

That's all done during build time so during runtime you can load that texture like this (assume *bundle* is of type [`AssetBundle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.html)):

```
bundle.LoadAsset("DogTexture");
```

instead of:

```
bundle.LoadAsset("Assets/Textures/stinky_pupper_smol.jpg");
```

---

For your second question, yes. The overload of [BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles.html) with an `AssetBundleBuild[]` as an argument will ignore your bundles identified in the editor:

> This variant of the function lets you specify the names and contents
>   of the bundles using a "build map" rather than with the details set in
>   the editor. The map is simply an array of AssetBundleBuild objects,
>   each of which contains a bundle name and a list of the names of asset
>   files to be added to the named bundle.